# document.form.field.value not giving value in Linux machine

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser

I have problem getting value with ajax function `document.form.field.value` in any browser in Linux machine. Things are working fine in any browser in Windows machine. But not Linux.

I get an error saying ajaxform undefined when I inspect in firebug console mode. I put screen shot if needed. The highlight in gray color in screen shot should give value as k.

[image]

Video link for more reference below.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxpw9853s0zanmz/ajax_problem_in%20_linux.ogv?dl=0

```
<form name="ajaxform">
    <input type="text" name="editingtext"/>
    <a href="#" onclick="getajax(document.ajaxform.editingtext.value);"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

have you written this ajax result to DOM using `.html()` ?

The highlight in gray color in screen shot should **not** give value as k because you are rendering the form through ajax call. Once the onClick event is triggered, then only the value will get.

Comment: Dinoop ji, thank you for response. I share video for more references